# VMware Server 2: I Installed Win Server 2003 64Bit, but can´t install 64Bit-Software in Guest-System

Tags: windows, windows-server-2003, vmware-server, 64-bit, x86-64

i have a question concerning VMware Server 2. I have an x86_64 architecture hostsystem.

I prepared my BIOS (vi enabled) to be able to install WIN Server 2003 64Bit-System (Guest).

The installation was succesful, but now when i try to install a software (64 bit sql server 2008 express) in the guest-system, i get the failure "software is not compatible with this system".

In the windows systeminformation menü i get the information, that the architecture of my guest-system is x86. But this has to be x64, when i was able to install a Win64bit-system, hasn´t it?

Did i do something wrong?

Thanks in advance for every answer,

Tim.

Answer (score 0):

So let's get this right first, you have a working Windows Server 2003 VM that's running fine but it reports it's 32-bit not 64-bit is that right?

If it is then that's because you specifically installed from a 32-bit Windows Server 2003 DVD/image - they come in either 32 **OR** 64 bit versions. As as you say SQL 2008 **NEEDS** a 64-bit OS.

If I've misunderstood your question perhaps you could re-word it (your English is better than my German though :) ).